# Alexa skill responding Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

```
const FactIntentHandler = {
        canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return (request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'GetFactIntent');
        //&& Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GetFactIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    var newFact = pitFile.facts[Math.floor(Math.random() * pitFile.fact.length)];//search for fact to return in random order 000561
    var factResult = newFact.text; // store fact 000561
    //speakoutput is a var and not a const because we want it to change 000561
    var speakOutput = "Here's why we love pits:" + factResult;

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
        //.reprompt(speakOutput)
        .getResponse();
  }
};
```

This is my code, I am using the hello world template. I edited the built in helloworld intent but when I call the getfactintent I get an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an Alexa Hosted skill, try the CloudWatch link in the lower left of the code panel. The logs should contain an error message if there is one.

When you grab the random fact, you use an array "pitFile.fact", but get the length of "pitFile.facts" in the random number generation. One would think these should be the same.

Since they're not, you're probably getting an error that it "can't read property length of undefined" or that pitFile.fact is not an array. That would show up in the CloudWatch logs.

Answer (score 0):

How did you asked? Real or via the "Test" tab in the skill console?

If real: Try to do the same in the skill console and test your skill. You will see a response and probably a more detailed error explanation in the JSON response on the right side.

Comment: I asked via the test tab, searched for an error message there was none

Comment: on revising the output given by the panels on the right, I have noticed that Alexa is registering the launch request as a session end request how do I stop this ??

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error, on line 8 the code
var newFact = pitFile.facts[Math.floor(Math.random() * pitFile.fact.length)];//search for fact to return in random order 000561

"pitFile.fact.length" should actually be "pitFile.facts.length"